# Setting default value in dropdown when using API to filter and fill the dropdown options

Tags: javascript, html, angular, drop-down-menu, typeahead

I have a page where there are more than 10 dropdowns which uses some API to fetch the options. We only fetch 20 options by default and for rest we have given search box in the dropdown to further filter the dropdown (Similar to typeahead. When user types the text, new set of dropdown options loads from server).

Something like this:
[image]

**The page can be viewed in display and edit mode.**

User have selected all the dropdowns with their values in page's edit mode and saved it to database. We store only **key** in the database for each dropdown option ( each option is key value pair).

Coming to the question:-

When user comes to the page in view mode, how do we select the default values for each dropdown, since the dropdown shows default value only if it's present in the options loaded. And we only load 20 options by default and the option selected by user is not present in the initial API call.

How to resolve this case?

What I tried: (Unsure if it's right because there are two api calls for each drop down in worst case)

1. If default value is not present in the options loaded intially, then make a API call to the backend with default key and get the value from the server and append it into the options of dropdown and then select the default value.

Comment: Do you have influence over the API to have your request that loads page data also include the "value" in the selected keys of the entity being loaded into the page?

Comment: Yes, we can modify the response on client side but we only have the key for the default value of drop down.

If we add the key how will drop down show the value for that key?